# How can I define a fallback command to be called if a command is not available

Tags: bash, shell, taskfile

I want to call `task` (https://taskfile.dev/) in a single line command. But on some systems task is installed as `task`, while on others as `go-task`. On my system I have defined an alias in the shell `task=go-task`.

Is there some concisely syntax:

```
task --help
```

maybe similar to default variable values, `${task:-go-task} --help` ?

This would be helpful in cases like, `podman` and `docker` or many more as well.

**edit:**

```
if command -v task &> /dev/null ; then task=task ; else task=go-task ; fi && $task --help
```

does not work, since `task` is an alias. In this case I get `bash: task: command not found...`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```bash
# Check command

command -v main-command > /dev/null && CMD=main-command || CMD=fallback-command

# Execute command

${CMD}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was to slow editing my question with more or less the same as MNWE.

Comment: Sorry, but I answered on the first version of your post. I'm going to read your update...

Comment: The solution depends on how you **alias** is defined. Please report it.

Comment: Maybe it is not to obvious in my question, "On my system I have defined an alias in the shell task=go-task.". Actually the defining line is `alias task='go-task'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function (instead of alias) :

```
task(){
    declare -a cmds=($FUNCNAME go-task) cmd c
    for c in "${cmds[@]}"; do
        type -f "$c" &> /dev/null && { cmd="$c"; break; }
    done
    test -v cmd && command $cmd "$@" ||
        { echo "bash: commands [${cmds[*]}] not found."; return 127; }
}
```